# firing the second .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I think this is very newbie question but is it possible to have 2 separate function on a .click on 1st and 2nd click?

```
$(div).click(function(){
    alert("1st click");
},
function(){
    alert("2nd click");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2xe8a/

Or is there any suggestion that would separate that function?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you talking about literally the second click or  [dblclick](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)?

Comment: OP please be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to do with the click event

Comment: Hi guys, all your codes are working but I was hoping for a permanent clicks(not just limited to 2 clicks), I think setting it up as an odd or even click. I just want something that will allow me to have a separate function for my even and odd clicks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just set something when clicked the first time and check it the second time

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this).data('clicked');

    if ( clicked ) {
        alert('the rest of the time');
    }else{
        alert('first time');
    }

    $(this).data('clicked', !clicked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2xe8a/10/)

Comment: Your code is working but is there a way to set it up as forever function. I don't know maybe setting it up as an odd and even clicks?

Comment: is it possible to add an element to do the same function on just the second click? I updated the fiddle so you will have a better understanding of what im trying to do? if its only possible? http://jsfiddle.net/2xe8a/11/

Comment: This might work, but is it possible to blend your second script with the first one? The thing is that, I have a long script and for some reason, a function doesn't work on my second "click" script?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to unbind on the first click:

```
function click1 () {
    alert('1st click');
    $(this).off('click', click1).on('click', click2);
}
function click2 () {
    alert('2nd click');
}

$(function () {
    $('#click').on('click', click1);
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xe8a/1/

Another option would be to use a wrapper method to determine which method is supposed to fire:

```
function click1 () {
    alert('1st click');
}
function click2 () {
    alert('2nd click');
}

$(function () {
    $('#click').data('clicks', 0).on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            clicks = $this.data('clicks') + 1;
        switch (clicks) {
            case 1: click1.call(this); break;
            case 2: click2.call(this); break;
        }
        $this.data('clicks', clicks);
    });
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xe8a/6/

Edit: As per Juhana's suggestion, a 3rd option might look like this:

```
function click2 () {
    alert('2nd click');
}

$(function () {
    $('#click').one('click', function () {
        alert('1st click');
        $(this).one('click', click2);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/2xe8a/8/

Comment: You can also use `.one()` for the first click so you don't need to unbind it manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want each function to happen once, you can use `one` instead of `on` (and, I always use something like `on('click')` instead of the shortcut `click()` method):

```
$("#click").one('click', function(){
  alert("1st click");
  $("#click").one('click', function(){
    alert("2nd click");
  });
});
```

If you need a little more control over which one fires, you can use `on` and then `off` to unbind the event handlers:

```
$("#click").on('click', function(){
  alert("1st click");
  $("#click").off('click');
  $("#click").on('click', function(){
    alert("2nd click");
    $("#click").off('click');
  });
});
```

If you want to do it with variables, you could do:

```
var firstClick = true;
$("#click").on('click', function(){
  if (firstClick) {
     alert("1st click");
     firstClick = false;
  }
  else {
    alert("2nd click");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of what exactly you are trying to do.

If you are trying to have the 2nd function execute every 2nd click (i.e even number of clicks), and execute the 1st function on the odd number of clicks, then why not use a counter?

This is a very simple example but I think it illustrates the principle:

```
var count = 0;
$("#click").click(function(){
    if (count % 2 === 0) {
        oddNumberOfClicks();
    }
    else {
        evenNumberOfClicks();
    }

    count++;
});

function oddNumberOfClicks() {
    alert('Doing some work for odd');
}

function evenNumberOfClicks() {
    alert('Doing some work for even');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2xe8a/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    var count = 0;

    $("#click").click(function(e){
        if(count % 2 == 0){
            count++;
            alert(1);
            // first click
        }else{
            count++;
            alert(2);
            // second click
        }
    });
});
```

Using a `count`er.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2xe8a/)**

P.S. This thing can be done without jQuery. http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: I saw nothing wrong with your answer personally. I don't know who downvoted it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it should be noted that you have a global variable and a selector that could potentially match multiple elements.

Comment: @adeneo See edit. I too don't like globals, and prefer IIFE always.

Comment: @adeneo Well the OP's question seems to be a bit general and this is a code snippet. Otherwise, the examples would have code within self executing anonymous functions or closures.

Comment: Uhm, that doesn't help much, what I was thinking about is that if you have two or more DIV's and you click one, the count will be  increased so when you click another DIV you get alert(2) on the first click.

Comment: @adeneo I get the point you try to make. As such, if I had known there might be more than one element I would have given a `.dataset.count` solution. This solution by me was indeed a bit general, and intended for a single-div use only.

Comment: No problem, I was just *noting* it, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
var t = false;
$("#click").click(
    function(){
        if(!t){
            alert("1st click");
            t = true;
        } else {
            alert("2st click");
        }
      }
);
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2xe8a/9/

Answer (score 0):

Using an incrementing variable?

```
clicks = 0;
$(div).click(function(){

  clicks = clicks +1; // clicks++
  if ( clicks == 1 ) {
    alert("1st click");
  } else if ( clicks == 2 ) {
    alert("2nd click");
  } else {
     //...
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

By 2nd click do you mean a double click? If so, there is a double click method in jQuery:

```
$(div).dblclick( function() {
    alert("asdf");
});
```